# Exporting excel worksheet to CSV via VBA with formula results shown

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel workbook with multiple sheets, i'm trying to export a particular sheet as a CSV file and save it to the users desktop without impacting the original.  Everything seems to work, however the file is coming out as a PDF, any ideas?  Code is below:

```
Sub CSVSagePricelist_Click()

Dim wsA As Worksheet
Dim wbA As Workbook
Dim TempWB As Workbook
Dim strTime As String
Dim strName As String
Dim strPath As String
Dim strFile As String
Dim strPathFile As String
Dim myFile As Variant
On Error GoTo errHandler

Set wbA = ActiveWorkbook
Set wsA = Sheet8
strTime = Format(Now(), "yyyymmdd\_hhmm")

'get active workbook folder, if saved
strPath = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").specialfolders("Desktop")
If strPath = "" Then
strPath = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").specialfolders("Desktop")
End If
strPath = strPath & "\"

'replace spaces and periods in sheet name
strName = Replace(wsA.Name, " ", "")
strName = Replace(strName, ".", "_")

'create default name for saving file
strFile = "INT-ONLY-SAGE-PRICELIST" & "_" & Sheet16.Range("C17").Text & "_"     & Sheet16.Range("B2").Text & ".csv"
strPathFile = strPath & strFile

'use can enter name and
'select folder for file
myFile = Application.GetSaveAsFilename _
(InitialFileName:=strPathFile, _
    FileFilter:="CSV (Comma delimited) (*.csv), *.csv", _
    Title:="Select Folder and FileName to save")

'export to PDF if a folder was selected
If myFile <> "False" Then
    wsA.ExportAsFixedFormat _
        Type:=xlCSV, _
        Filename:=myFile
    'confirmation message with file info
    MsgBox "Sage pricebook CSV created: " _
      & vbCrLf _
      & myFile
End If

exitHandler:
    Exit Sub
errHandler:
    MsgBox "Could not create CSV file"
    Resume exitHandler
End Sub
```

Thanks,
Nick

Comment: `xlCSV` is not a [XlFixedFormatType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.xlfixedformattype?view=excel-pia). Invalid type arguments probably just default to 0 and give you a PDF.

Comment: `SaveAs` instead of `ExportAsFixedFormat` should work.

Answer (score 0):

Following code lines / code blocks are needed to corrected. Also you should include `Option Explicit` in the beginning of code so that undeclared variables are easily identified.

A.)

`Set wsA = Sheet8`

Will give Compiler error. Variable not defined. It should be changed to

```
Set wsA = Sheets("Sheet8")
```

Similarly

```
      strFile = "INT-ONLY-SAGE-PRICELIST" & "_" & Sheet16.Range("C17").Text & "_"     & Sheet16.Range("B2").Text & ".csv"
strPathFile = strPath & strFile
```

It should be changed to

```
      strFile = "INT-ONLY-SAGE-PRICELIST" & "_" & Sheets("Sheet16").Range("C17").Text & "_" & Sheets("Sheet16").Range("B2").Text & ".csv"
strPathFile = strPath & strFile
```

B.)    Block of code for saving as pdf file has incorrect syntax.

```
  If myFile <> "False" Then
        wsA.ExportAsFixedFormat _
            Type:=xlCSV, _
            Filename:=myFile
        'confirmation message with file info
         MsgBox "Sage pricebook CSV created: " _
          & vbCrLf _
          & myFile
    End If
```

Needs to be Changed to

```
        'export to PDF if a folder was selected
If myFile <> "False" Then
    wsA.ExportAsFixedFormat _
        Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        Filename:=myFile, _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=False
    'confirmation message with file info
    MsgBox "PDF file has been created: " _
      & vbCrLf _
      & myFile
End If
```

With these changes your final code should work fine.

```
Option Explicit
Sub CSVSagePricelist_Click()

Dim wsA As Worksheet
Dim wbA As Workbook
Dim TempWB As Workbook
Dim strTime As String
Dim strName As String
Dim strPath As String
Dim strFile As String
Dim strPathFile As String
Dim myFile As Variant
On Error GoTo errHandler

Set wbA = ActiveWorkbook
Set wsA = Sheets("Sheet8")
strTime = Format(Now(), "yyyymmdd\_hhmm")

'get active workbook folder, if saved
strPath = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").specialfolders("Desktop")
If strPath = "" Then
strPath = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").specialfolders("Desktop")
End If
strPath = strPath & "\"

'replace spaces and periods in sheet name
strName = Replace(wsA.Name, " ", "")
strName = Replace(strName, ".", "_")

'create default name for saving file
strFile = "INT-ONLY-SAGE-PRICELIST" & "_" & Sheets("Sheet16").Range("C17").Text & "_" & Sheets("Sheet16").Range("B2").Text & ".csv"
strPathFile = strPath & strFile

'use can enter name and
'select folder for file
myFile = Application.GetSaveAsFilename _
(InitialFileName:=strPathFile, _
    FileFilter:="CSV (Comma delimited) (*.csv), *.csv", _
    Title:="Select Folder and FileName to save")

'export to PDF if a folder was selected
If myFile <> "False" Then
    wsA.ExportAsFixedFormat _
        Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        Filename:=myFile, _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=False
    'confirmation message with file info
    MsgBox "PDF file has been created: " _
      & vbCrLf _
      & myFile
End If

exitHandler:
    Exit Sub
errHandler:
    MsgBox "Could not create CSV file"
    Resume exitHandler
End Sub
```